# Azure WebJob with schedule 409 response on deployment

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, schedule, azure-webjobs

Have an issue when we try to deploy webjob to a web app via Visual Studio.

If we try to set 10 minutes interval it returns 409 response
http://grab.by/Rirs

If we try with one hour interval it is successful.

We have `Standard` app service plan, so it should be supported.
http://grab.by/Rirw

`Always on` is activated for web app. 
We have also tried another approach that described [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.V34Uy7h965t)
There is `Publish Succeeded.` but if we look on webjob in VS Cloud Explorer it has `Fail` status

Any ideas how can we solve it?

Comment: how many webjob running on your website currently? Did you try to use Azure Scheduler?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Thanks for attention, already found the way to resolve the issue

Comment: Nice. Congratulation!

Answer (score 1):

After some researching, found the issue, but actually in old Azure portal. 
It was necessary to set `standard` tier for the job collections that was created for jobs under web-apps.

New portal doesn't have simple way to get that (or I didn't find it as simple like I done that with old portal) and again the super-fine thing it's possibility to configure job schedule on the old portal, while it's not possible on new one... or again I didn't find that